# The best way to distribute a widget in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

I built a graphics component (it extends uiview) in iOS and I would like distribute it easily to everyone who wants insert it into his mobile app. It's not strictly necessary that the code is closed. I can make this component opensource.

Requirements:

- easy to integrate into a mobile app
- easy to use: only an entry point
- easy to distribute: no many files

Which is the best way to achieve this goal? Library, Framework or what else?

Thanks!
aGO!

Comment: Answer to all your requirements is good design. Look at currently available open source components like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), etc. Check the design they follow. Should be good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your code on [GitHub](https://github.com/) or any other similar service, allowing people to download the source, and also considerer to create a podspec to make it available through [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/). I don't know how to do that, I imagine you have to request to upload your podspec or something, but definitely I will try to do it since CocoaPods is a very nice and clean way of managing dependencies and IMO will be more and more used.

Answer (score 0):

You can post your code or project on github.com, bitbucket.com, sourceforge.com
This are the most popular source to make a project opensource & distribute publicly

You can also post your app at app store other than apple app store http://freeappaday.com/